# Enforcing uniqueness on PostgreSQL table column after non-unique values already inserted

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, duplicates

I already have 80 million records inserted into a table, but need to ensure a few columns are jointly unique. However, the columns already contain non-unique data, so ALTER TABLE doesn't work.

I'd like either a query that will let me easily delete records that are non-unique, while keeping one of them, or one that will allow me to load the data from the current table into a new one, while filtering for uniqueness.

Comment: Do you have a criterion for picking which row to keep and which to discard when uniqueness is violated for these columns?

Comment: Yes, a date column. I'd keep the most recent records. If those are also duplicate for some reason, either one can go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query you're looking for is:

```
select distinct on (my_unique_1, my_unique_2) * from my_table;
```

This selects one row for each combination of columns within `distinct on`. Actually, it's always *the first* row. It's rarely used without `order by` since there is no reliable order in which the rows are returned (and so which is the first one).

Combined with `order by` you can choose which rows are the first (this leaves rows with the greatest last_update_date):

```
 select distinct on (my_unique_1, my_unique_2) * 
 from my_table order by my_unique_1, my_unique_2, last_update_date desc;
```

Now you can select this into a new table:

```
 create table my_new_table as
 select distinct on (my_unique_1, my_unique_2) * 
 from my_table order by my_unique_1, my_unique_2, last_update_date desc;
```

Or you can use it for delete, assuming `row_id` is a primary key:

```
 delete from my_table where row_id not in (
     select distinct on (my_unique_1, my_unique_2) row_id 
     from my_table order by my_unique_1, my_unique_2, last_update_date desc);
```

Comment: About "the first row":  Without an ORDER BY, there is no way to tell which row will come back first, so the "first row" is a misleading term as you may not always get the same result.  A DISTINCT ON is pretty much useless without an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: I read about distinct, but I tried use it with `Limit 1000` as well, just to check the output. Was taking forever, but I assume that's because I had to remove indexes temporarily to insert more data quickly. Thanks for the clear example, but I'm confused about the `my_unique` columns after `distinct on`. The docs say that those should be expressions, so does including the columns as expressions just make sure they are present in the record? I ask because I actually need to make sure those columns are not just present, but jointly unique.